# ¿es un java `project` solo un archivo?

Tags: java

Necesito estructurar correctamente un proyecto de formas en el que desarrollará un paquete `view`, un paquete `model` y un paquete `controller`.

No sé si los "Projects" son objetos Java por derecho propio. Pregunté sobre [la documentación de Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-java-project.htm) y leí eso:

> *El proyecto Java contiene código fuente y archivos relacionados para el programa Java. Tiene un generador de Java asociado que puede compilar incrementalmente los archivos fuente de Java a medida que se modifican.*

Deduje que se referían a javac.

Por lo tanto, ¿es un java `project` solo un archivo simple?

Si eso es correcto, entonces me piden que cree una nueva vista de paquete en el proyecto de `view` y cree una clase `MyDisplay` que hereda la clase `JPanel`.

¿Significa esto que un paquete es un simple archivo java como el siguiente?

```
package view;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MyDisplay extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String []args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Avancé - Graphic Display");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyDisplay d = new MyDisplay();
        frame.add(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**¿Un Java project es un sólo archivo?** La respuesta es no. Es un conjunto de carpetas y archivos para un propósito (el que le quieras dar).

Los proyectos Java pueden estar divididos en subdirectorios, contener archivos de configuración (XML, Properties, etc.) y contener librerías (JARs).

**Ejemplo.** En Maven/Gradle se debe respetar una jerarquía. En la siguiente imagen se puede apreciar el nombre del proyecto (testJava) y sus subcarpetas:

> src\main
>       main\java
>       main\resources
>
> src\test
>       test\java
>       test\resources
>
> build.gradle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sirva está explicación.